# sha: hashed values not matching,when hashed on different pages

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sha

I am using sha1 alogorithm for hashing password,& store it in DB.

I have tried following,in aspx page

1.
*Login.aspx*

```
  function enc()
  {
   var x=document.getElementById("<%=txtPwd.ClientID %>").value;
   var hash = CryptoJS.SHA1(x);
   alert(hash); 
   alert(typeof hash);
   return false;
  }
```

*Changepwd.aspx*

```
  function enc()
  {
   var confirmp=$("#txtConfrimPassword").val();
   var hash = CryptoJS.SHA1(confirmp);
   alert(hash);
   document.getElementById("<%=txtConfrimPassword.ClientID%>").value = hash; 
   document.getElementById("<%=txtNewPassword.ClientID%>").value = hash; 
   return false;
  }
```

2  tried:  var id2 = $.sha1(String(id)); alternative also..

but in both cases, changed password is not matching while logging in.

**Observation: the values hashed by the pages for same values are different!**

Problem: How can I get, same values from both the pages. or where I went wrong, am i missing somthing?
Please guide me.

edit:

**outputs: for value: abc1234**

1 login: c9b359951c09c5d04de4f852746671ab2b2d0994

2 changepwd: da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709

Comment: The first obvious troubleshooting step is to inspect the unencrypted values with `console.log()`. I can see some alerts out there so already thought about that, but didn't share the results with us. Also, please note that leading or trailing spaces might be difficult to spot but affect the result.

Comment: okey thanks! Now I have added the results.

Comment: That's not what I asked for but I think it helps to solve the problem as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709` is the SHA1 hash for a empty string. Your `confirmp` variable does not contain any password at all. You can verify it with any browser that supports console:

```
var confirmp=$("#txtConfrimPassword").val();
console.log(confirmp);
```

I have the impression that you've made a simple typo:

```
txtConfrimPassword
   ^^^^^^^
```

Comment: yes, just checked on console, log is : is not defined! Thanks, to track the problem.

Comment: @ Alvaro: can we achieve same value on server side hashing using SHA1 algo?

Comment: I'm not a .NET programmer, but I'm pretty sure it has encryption tools.